# Using "Visual Studio Dev Essentials" Azure Subscription with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-ad-b2c

I have just set up an Azure AD B2C directory with my current Azure account and I was wondering if anyone knew of a way for me to use that subscription inside the newly created directory?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. That's a subscription question for Azure's support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login to manage.windowsazure.com and scroll down and click on 'Settings'
2. Here you will see a list of Subscriptions
3. Select the required subscription and then click the 'Edit Directory' link on the bottom panel
4. In the resulting dialog box you have the option to select from a list of existing Active Directories to which you would like to move the subscription.